# Unable to get number of likes in an array php

Tags: php, arrays, facebook, multidimensional-array

I am using the following code to get the number of likes on a page.

```
        <?php
    $site="http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http%3a%2f%2fXXXXXXXX/svce.php";
    $graph= file_get_contents($site);

    $json_string=$graph; 
    $array  = json_decode($json_string, true);

    //echo "<pre>";
    //print_r($array);

    $var = $array['shares'];
    echo $var;


    ?>
```

But whenever i try to echo out the following code. I always get an unidentified index Notice which is as following: Notice: Undefined index: shares in C:\xampp\htdocs\graphapi.php on line 19

Where am i going wrong?

Here's the print_r output:

```
 Array
(
     [http://xxxxxxxxx/svce.php] => Array

    (
        [id] => http://xxxxxxxxx/svce.php
        [shares] => 7
        [comments] => 3
     )

 )
```

Comment: could you provide the `print_r` output?

Comment: @JohannesMittendorfer i just edited the question and added the print_r output to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According your print out  looks like there is an array more in `$array`. Try this;

```
echo $array['http://xxxxxxxxx/svce.php']['shares'];
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks for your help. I will accept the answer as correct, it still has a 5 minutes time off left

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the site-name as an key before.

Structure:

```
- http://example.com
  - id
  - shares
```

This means in PHP:

```
$array["http://example.com/path/to/site"]["shares"];
```

Comment: I am sorry but i didn't understand what u meant by the above. Can you please be a little more breif ?